# adding an arraylist in basicvaluepair

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i need to post a parameter like this.

```
[uangMuka:0.00, description:lsdkjfasldfjkad;slkfjaslkfjaslkdfjaw, 
 item:[5, 4],     
 qty:[1.00, 50.00],     
 unit:[1, 1],     
 price:[100000.00, 50000.00],     
 discount:[10.00, 10.00],     
 dt:[PS, PS]]
```

from android, i use this code to put the key and value

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uangMuka", "100"));
parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
```

the question is how can i fill the `value` with `arraylist` like 
 parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", [1,2])); //for example this `item` has 2 value.

i tried to put a list in `BasicNameValuePair` like this

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");

ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", list));
```

Comment: You coudl rewrite `BasicNameValuePair`'s constructor to expect a `String id, String... values` or `String id, Object... values` and use this array to identify more than one assigned value

Comment: is theres no other ways? or can you give me example?
i really not get it @KevinEsche

Comment: @Jobin is theres no other ways? or can you give me example? i really not get it

Comment: @Jobin i tried not to use `BasicNameValuePair`, for example , i tried to use `HashMap` and i tried to put an arraylist to `value` like this `BasicNameValuePair("id", Arraylist)` where ArrayList is [1,2]

Comment: @Jobin because it not work at all, i am trying to find other solution with `BasicNameValuePair`

Comment: @Jobin see my update question, like that

Comment: post BasicNameValuePair as well

Comment: You have to write a method that will create `[item1, item2]` from any list

Comment: @Jobin did you mean it will working?

Comment: Alternatively, why can't you `toString` the lists?

Comment: @cricket_007 did you mean change the `key` ?

Comment: No? Why do you think that? The key is `item` the value is the list `[5, 4]`

Comment: @cricket_007 `unit:[1, 1]` this one, when i get paramater unit, the value is `String` not the `ArrayList`, but in server need to receive `array`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how the server accepts values

Comment: Honestly, if you used JSON, it'd be much easier to get "an array"

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, i tried to create a string like this `String a = "[" `
then `a=a+"1";` `a=a+"4"`then `a=a+"]"`.. but the server still read as string not arraylist

Comment: @cricket_007 did you mean receive as JSON?

Comment: Right... HTTP sends strings, nothing else

Comment: Send and receive. Besides, Apache HTTP is deprecated within Android. Retrofit or OkHttp make POSTing data pretty simple

Comment: @cricket_007 i see, i think this is the last choice, because we need to change server's code, but is theres any way?

Comment: It's not clear how your server code works or how it expects an array. I've only dealt with REST APIs that use JSON, so sorry, not sure how to help more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your choice of the collection could be simplified into the following signature (as you want to get rid of the *`BasicNameValuePair`*):

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> BasicNameValuePair = new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> ();
```

The usage:

```
 Map<String,ArrayList<String>> BasicNameValuePair = new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> ();

        ArrayList<String> v1 = new ArrayList<>();
        v1.add("5");
        v1.add("4");  
        BasicNameValuePair.put("items",v1);

        ArrayList<String> v2 = new ArrayList<>();
        v2.add("1.00");
        v2.add("50.00");  
        BasicNameValuePair.put("qty",v2);
```